# Checking if a file exists and if it doesn't creating it from embedded resource

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource

I don't know why I can't get this to work, I have found lots of answers on google but none of them seem to work for me.

My program requires a file on disk called "wordlist.txt" at runtime, in the same directory as the executable. So I have in my constructor code to check whether it exists, and if not to create it by copping it from the embedded resource

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 

    if (!File.Exists("wordlist.txt")) 
    {
        byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(Properties.Resources.wordlist);
        File.WriteAllBytes("wordlist.txt", ba); 
    }
}
```

It tells me I have illegal characters in my path though.

Comment: What is the value of `Properties.Resources.wordlist`? `File.ReadAllBytes` takes a filename as its first parameter.

Comment: wordlist is just a .txt file that I have added as an emberred resource. It passes the syntax check like that and if I type "byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(Properties.Resources.wordlist);" it doesn't

Comment: You're probably looking for something like the answer to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: And you can check the name of your resource with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are storing the default word list as a resource.  If you are, you probably need something like,

```
if (!File.Exists("wordlist.txt"))
{
    File.WriteAllText("wordlist.txt", Properties.Resources.wordlist);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using the full path like @"c:\worldlist.txt" instead of just the filename?

Comment: That wouldn't be causing the illegal characters in path exception though.

Comment: The thing is I don't know the path of name. its a portable exe and I have to place the .txt file wherever the user is running the exe

Comment: you can get the path of an executable

Comment: here are a couple ways of getting it:http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-application-directory/